# Relation Composition and Set Equality

Tags: relations

I am stuck on a relation composition problem from book [1]. The context is: Suppose $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Let $D_r = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |x-y| < r\}$, and $D_s = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |x-y| < s\}$. The problem is only: what is $D_r \circ D_s$?

From the definition of composition of relations, 
\begin{align}
D_r \circ D_s &= \{(x, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(xD_sy\ \text{and}\ yD_rz)\} \\
&= \{(x, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \exists y \in \mathbb{R}(|x-y| < s\ \text{and}\ |y-z| < r)\}.
\end{align}
The book hints to use the triangle inequality $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\forall y \in \mathbb{R}(|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|)$. My suspicion is that the intended answer is 
\begin{equation}
D_r \circ D_s = \{(x, z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |x - z| < s + r\}.
\end{equation}
(If it isn't, then I fail to see how the triangle inequality relates.) But for this to be the case it must be that
\begin{equation}
\exists y \in \mathbb{R} (|x-y| < s\ \text{and}\ |y-z| < r) \leftrightarrow |x - z| < s + r
\end{equation}
given the above assumptions on $r, s, x, y$. 
Proving ($\rightarrow$) is straightforward: suppose the LHS is true, choose some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x - y| < s$ and $|y - z| < r$, then $|x - y| + |y - z| < s + r$, but $|x - z| = |(x - y) + (y - z)| \leq |x - y| + |y - z|$ (triangle inequality), so $|x - z| < s + r$.

How to prove ($\leftarrow$) is not clear to me. After assuming the RHS, is there a particular value of $y \in \mathbb{R}$ that I can choose to make the LHS true?

---

[1] Velleman, Daniel. *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach* 2e, Ch. 4 Sec. 3 Prob 6.